# how to chose one implimentation in queryDSL

Tags: sql, jpa, querydsl

I want to work with querydsl but I have a probleme when I call from(...) function

```
            UserTransaction tx = TM.getUserTransaction();
            tx.begin();

            EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
            JPAQueryFactory x = new JPAQueryFactory(new 
              Provider<EntityManager>() {
                @Override
                public EntityManager get() {
                    return em;
                }});
            JPAQuery query = x.query();
            query.from(typeInstitutionEntity)[`enter image description here`][https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7rcw.png]
```

Comment: What is the problem you are getting? What are you expecting?

Comment: you can see the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7rcw.png code not compile  query.from() there is two implimentation !!!!